# How to stop a recorded macro at File > Save As

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Context: I created 30 spreadsheets with names (first & last) plus email addresses. Unfortunately, after completing this work I learned 2 things:

1. My column order was out of order per the specs of the website where I need to upload these files for the purpose of sending out a survey.
2. To be uploadable, the file must be `.csv` not `.xlsx`.

I have managed to record a macro that:

1. cuts/pastes column D (email addresses) to Column G
2. selects Cols A, B, C, and D and then deletes them.

Doing so means my first data cell is located in A1.

However, when I continued recording the macro by stepping into "file save as", I couldn't find a way to STOP RECORDING.

Is it possible to edit the macro such that after completing steps #1 and #2 above, the following actions happen?:

1. execute "file save as" command
2. change file type from .xlsx to .csv (without user intervention)
3. pause macro to allow user to manually enter unique file name
4. saves renamed file to original directory.

Comment: Need to....????

Comment: I'm sure you'd expect your students to present complete questions. This is not a complete question. Please use the EDIT button to make it into one.

Comment: [this may be of use](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)